# Extra characters when make response with @ResponseBody annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I'm using @RequestMapping and @ResponseBody annotations to make a simple health check response (OK/FAILED) when a load balancer calls my application. 
This is my code:

```
@Controller

public class HealthCheck {

protected ir.iic.release.middleware.persistence.JDBCController JDBCController;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("JDBCController")
public void setJDBCController(JDBCController JDBCController) {
    this.JDBCController = JDBCController;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/healthCheck", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
String getHealthStatus() {
    long connectionStatus = 1;
    try {
        connectionStatus = JDBCController.queryForLong("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        connectionStatus = 0;
    }
    return (connectionStatus == 1 ? "OK" : "FAILED");
}
}
```

everything works fine when I call specified URL by a browser but load balancer does not accept the response. I checked response with WireShark utility to monitor packets, there is no problem in HTTP stream but in TCP stream it looks that exists extra characters before and after OK/FAILED response.
This is TCP stream:

```
GET /iic-auto/cluster/healthCheck HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.136.37:9001
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: JSESSIONID=3hdJcJXJPvVtbndx27hqrbcK81Qj7gFF660mLj5jnTXg5rWT26j0!-2081249701
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 15 Dec 2018 06:19:54 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

0002
OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 15 Dec 2018 06:19:54 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1

0002
OK
0000
```

Does anybody know how I can solve this problem?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `0002` is `stx` and `0000` is `null` in ASCII standard. I think the problem is related to the load balancer (not these characters). Would you please explain what is your load balancer package and how you configured that?

Comment: LoadBalancer=Cisco Ace  -------------- Configuration= https://i.ibb.co/pzLJ6cP/LB.jpg

Comment: According to Ace documentation, you can define regex for HTTP responses and that means you can easily ignore any additional characters in response. Unfortunately, the image you sent in response contains just a simple gui based configuration. I can help you more if you tell me how you configured the health check responses.

Comment: Additionally it seems that you have only `OK` and `FAILED` states, and therefore you can just set healthcheck based on http status response. It means that you can use `expect status 200 200` command on the Ace device and return non 200 responses in your service, if there is a problem in application.

Answer (score 0):

They are not `extra characters`.

They are part of control code used by `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`